# Can't sort files by date with a groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have an directory(jars) with many .jar files with different creation date.I tried to sort by date ascending/descending with the following code but not work.

```
Jar=[]
Date createdDate = new Date()
path = "/home/users/DIT/jars/"
new File(path).eachFileMatch(~/.*.jar/) {
      Jar.add(it.getName())
}  

return Jar.sort{it.createdDate}
```

I tried these but non of them works OK:

- `return Jar.sort{it.createdDate}` //no sorting by date
- `return Jar.sort{-it.createdDate}` //no sorting by date
- `return Jar.sort{createdDate}` //sorting by date only 1 file(last modified jar) and the other ones are in a random order
- `return Jar.sort{ a,b -> b.lastModified() <=> a.lastModified() }` //no sorting by date
- `return Jar.sort{a,b-> b.createdDate<=>a.createdDate}}` //no sorting by date

Comment: I haven't tried this, but my first thoughts are that those dates values are strings so possibly being sorted alphabetically rather than date.  Maybe you need to wirte a function that converts each date string (if that;s the issue, to a date then sort.

Comment: random nitpicking: naming your variables starting with uppercase letters (`Jar`) is against the convention and there are corner cases in the Groovy parser, where it things you want a class there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no property `createdDate` on File object

however there is a [`lastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--) method

so this should work:

```
Jar=[]
path = "/11/server/wso2ei-6.3.0/lib/"
new File(path).eachFileMatch(~/.*.jar/) {
      Jar.add(it)
}  

return Jar.sort{it.lastModified()}
```

if you want to return only names:

```
return Jar.sort{it.lastModified()}.collect{it.name}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but unfortunately, don't work...:(

Comment: the problem that you put into an array names (strings). but to be able to sort you have to store File object. Modified the answer with full working code.